# How to organize Android dialog IDs?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, organization

I have a base class `ActivityA` that has some dialogs:

```
public static final int SOME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
public static final int OTHER_DIALOG_ID = 2;
```

`ActivityB` inherits `ActivityA` and comes with its own dialogs:

```
public static final int MY_DIALOG_ID = 1;
public static final int CONFLICT_DIALOG_ID = 2;
```

As you can see, the dialog IDs are no longer unique within the activity. This is a problem that I keep running into. Easy to fix, but tedious to maintian. There must be some good design pattern for this particular issue. Please, enlighten me!

**Q:** What is the best way to organize dialog IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my situation, I create class called `AppConstant.java` that contain all constant in current application, some of it:

```
public static final int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_ACT_MAIN_BROWSE_PICTURE = 1;
public static final int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_ACT_MAIN_CAMMERA_SNAP = 2;
public static final int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_ACT_PROCESS_IMAGE_PROCESS = 3;
public static final int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_ACT_PROCESS_BROWSE_PICTURE_FOR_BACK_DATA = 4;
```

Using this convention, I can easily maintain my ID within single class.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks! I also found this article: http://androiddevblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/sharing-complex-dialog-interactions-across-multiple-activities/

Answer (score 0):

How about use 1, 2 for ActivityA, then 11, 12 for inherited class, then 101, 102 (or 21, 22) for further inheritance depth.

Comment: That's what I did until now. It's hard to maintain :(